# Stuck in infinite fgets loop

Tags: c, while-loop, fgets

I'm trying to get a integer input, and I tried the most elementary method I could find. However, whenever something isn't a integer, it gets stuck in a infinite loop. I believe it's caused by the fgets funcion. I tried a few solutions I found on this site, but none worked. The code is as follows

```
int getint()
{
    int number;
    char input[4];

    fgets(input, 4, stdin);
    while ( atoi(input) < 0 || ( strcmp(input, "0") != 0 && atoi(input) == 0 ) )
        printf("Insert a non negative number: ");
        fgets(input, 4, stdin);
    number = atoi(input);
    printf("%d\n", number);

    return number;
}
```

Comment: Indentation does not control flow make.

Comment: You must have braces for multi-line code blocks.

Comment: @KerrekSB Python and Lua seem to be leaking.

Comment: Since `fgets()` includes the newline (if the buffer is large enough), `strcmp(input, "0") != 0` will always be true unless end of file was reached right after the '0'...

Comment: @EOF Python, sure. Lua doesn't care about indentation in the least. Forgetting to `end` is a syntax error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are more than one statements that you want to write in a loop or if statement, then you must use braces `{}` to define which statements come in the loop.

In your code, only the `printf("Insert a non negative number: ");` statement is in the loop, and nothing is changing the `input`'s value in the loop, so if the loop's condition is true, it will always remain true.

Change it to:

```
while ( atoi(input) < 0 || ( strcmp(input, "0") != 0 && atoi(input) == 0 ) )
{
    printf("Insert a non negative number: ");
    fgets(input, 4, stdin);
}
```